# Instancing - make real and join - duplicates itself

Tags: objects, instances

I made object `A` where the instances will go, parented object `B` to it, and activated `Instancing on Verts` (under *Properties > Object Properties*).

The instances appear as desired. Then I did 'make instances real' (I get to that by searching). Then I chose all the created instances, and joined them (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>). Call that object `C`.

When I do that, object B becomes the same as object `C`. It duplicates itself the same way. In fact, if I then go in and edit object `C`, object `B` changes in the same way. And vice versa.

[image]

For me, this is the best way to do this. It allows me to export the combined object as a glTF and also keep the template object for later reuse or modification.

[image]

Comment: It looks like it is something about object B, the one that is being instanced. I am trying to sanitize it, but so far no luck. I tried copying the object, copying all the faces in edit mode and then separating them into a new object. It has no modifiers now, no constraints.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting, @brockmann

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because all objects use the same **Object Data**.
You need to make it unique before joining.

Select "realed instances" go to *Properties Editor > Data Properties* and click on a number on the first row. The "active" one (bright orange) become unique, now join them <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

(The number means how many objects in a scene use this data block.)

[image]